# get-website/get-webapplication associated directory

Tags: powershell, iis

If I wanted to find the directory associated with an IIS site or application, how would I do that?

I cannot seem to find anything on any properties of objects from `Get-Website` and `Get-WebApplication` that allow me to do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just look at the members of a web site:

```
get-website -Name "Default Web Site" | Get-Member
```

returns:

```
...
password                   NoteProperty          System.String password=
physicalPath               NoteProperty          System.String physicalPath=%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
serverAutoStart            NoteProperty          System.Boolean  serverAutoStart=True
...
```

that's pretty obvious to me:

```
(Get-Website -Name "Default Web Site").PhysicalPath
```

same for an Application:

```
(get-webapplication foo).PhysicalPath
```

Comment: I am completely blind, I had seen location and path properties but not that one. Thanks.